# mongodb lookup with foreign field match

Tags: mongodb, match, lookup

I want to know how can i lookup with match.

I could lookup two collection by this query.

```
 db.category.aggregate([
 {
     $lookup:
     {
       from: "faq",
       localField: "_id",
       foreignField: "category_code",
       as: "faq"
     }
  }
])
```

Then i get this result.

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("1234"),
   "category_name":"about account",
   "faq": [
      {
          "_id":ObjectId("faq id blah blah"),
          "category_code" : ObjectId("1234"),
          "faq_title":"When you can't create account",
          "del_flg":"N"
      },
      {
          "_id":ObjectId("faq id blah blah2222"),
          "category_code" : ObjectId("1234"),
          "faq_title":"When you change your account",
          "del_flg":"N"
      },
      {
          "_id":ObjectId("faq id blah blah3333"),
          "category_code" : ObjectId("1234"),
          "faq_title":"When you lost your account",
          "del_flg":"Y"
      }
   [
}
```

I want just two faq item which "del_flg" is "N"

I am not familiar to use mongodb.

Is it possible if i use pipline? I tried some pipline examples, but i couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [$lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup),

- let will create a variable to access id inside lookup pipeline using `$$`
- pipeline match using `$expr` because we are comparing both fields `$$id` = `$category_code`
- set match condition `del_flg`: `N`

```
db.category.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "faq",
      let: {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$id",
                "$category_code"
              ]
            },
            "del_flg": "N"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "faq"
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gUVUMk6KIAV